# Problema al implementar en Gradle Braintree en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Estoy intentando implementar en una aplicación Braintree y surge el siguiente problema. Cuando intento agregar la siguiente dependencia.

```
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.3.0'
```

Salta el siguiente Error :

> Error: Program type already present:
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior

Investigue y encontré que para corregirlo se agregar :

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Pero no funciono.

Cambien la version a la 27 y tampoco funciona, agradeceria muchisima una ayuda con este problema.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "termo.com.pagosbraintree2"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'



}
```

Answer (score 1):

veo que usas  `compileSdkVersion 28` y `targetSdkVersion 28` , el problema es seguramente que la library:

```
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.3.0'
```

esta usando el library de soporte pero de una versión diferente a la 28.

Te sugiero definir en como dependencia:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   ...
   ...
  }
```

Comment: Buenas noches ya aquí, gracias por tu respuesta.  Eso fue de lo primero que intente hacer, pero el error que salío fue mucho mayor.  
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'